# angular.element alternative from Angular 2 onwards

Tags: angular, typescript, dom

I have an Angular 1 application where I used:

```
let css = ".toolbar-background {background-color: #D3300E !important;}";

angular.element(document.body).append(angular.element('<div><style>' + css + '</style></div>'));
```

I am migrating my application to Angular 2 and now the `angular` object is not available from Angular 2 onwards.

It will be really helpful if someone can suggest a possible way to achieve the same in Angular 2.

Comment: `Renderer2` ? https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2

Comment: @wostex I have a <ion-navbar> tag in the html and I want to change the class properties. Is it possible to do this with Renderer2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are couple of ways to do this:

**USING DOCUMENT**

import Document in your component like this:

```
import {DOCUMENT} from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

inject it in the constructor like this:

```
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any) {

  }
```

and use it to append the data like this inside any function:

```
ngOnInit() {
    let css = ".toolbar-background {background-color: #D3300E !important;}";

    this.document.body.innerHTML.append = this.document.body.innerHTML + "<div><style>" + css + "</style></div>";
  }
```

here is the working plunker:

https://embed.plnkr.co/lVRcHNJnxgGsD1iwZJll/

**USING ElementRef**

Import ElementRef and ViewChild in component like this:

```
import {ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
```

In your html define the div in which you want to append data like:

```
<div #styleDiv></div>
```

Access above div using ViewChild like this:

```
 @ViewChild('styleDiv') styleDiv:ElementRef;
```

and perform the required append like this:

```
let css = "h2 {color: green;font-size:14px;}";
let tmp = "<style>" + css + "</style>";
this.styleDiv.nativeElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',tmp);
```

here is the working plunker using ViewChild and ElementRef: 
https://embed.plnkr.co/lVRcHNJnxgGsD1iwZJll/

Comment: In the plunker I tried :-

` let css = "h2 {color: green;}"; `

Not working

Comment: @SuneetJain it is working. Here is the plunker with let css = "h2{color: green;}"; 

https://embed.plnkr.co/lVRcHNJnxgGsD1iwZJll/

Comment: You have now removed the .append. Is it possible to achieve with Renderer2 ?

Comment: I am creating an example with ElemntRef and after that i will create an example with renderer 2. But you can use the above solution as well.

Comment: [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/ZapcewEnemeC0lDb5t2I/)

With append it takes the 'name' variable but then the css does not work.
Without append it does not take variable but then css works.

Comment: https://embed.plnkr.co/lVRcHNJnxgGsD1iwZJll/ just use this one as base. Name is there and everything else is working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149489/discussion-between-suneet-jain-and-fahad-nisar).

Comment: [Plunker ElementRef](https://embed.plnkr.co/lVRcHNJnxgGsD1iwZJll/)

This solution from @Fahad Nisar worked for me. Thanks a lot

Comment: ElementRef is not recommended by Angular docs, read the Security Guide on the corresponding official documentation [link](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) but they recommend to use [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2)

Comment: Now since `DOCUMENT` has been deprecated from `platform-browser`, you should edit the answer to use `import {DOCUMENT} from '@angular/common;'` instead of `import {DOCUMENT} from '@angular/platform-browser';`,

Answer (score 4):

you can use ElementRef and append css.

constructor(myElement: ElementRef) { ... }